# Why do we need a new object in bookshelf.js fetch() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm new to Node and using bookshelf.js as the ORM for my current project. The documentation of bookshelf.js contains this snippet under fetch() method:

```
// select * from `books` where `ISBN-13` = '9780440180296'
new Book({'ISBN-13': '9780440180296'})
  .fetch()
  .then(function(model) {
  // outputs 'Slaughterhouse Five'
  console.log(model.get('title'));
});
```

http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-fetch

What confuses me is why do we need to create a new object here if we are querying for an existing record? Does the way bookshelf.js works requires a new object to be created for every returned result?

Comment: `new Book({'ISBN-13': '9780440180296'})`?

Comment: That's how the API works.  You need to call a method on something, and you need to specify the query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing. At the moment there is only one type of object that represents both "model" and "query builder".

`fetch` prefills the `WHERE` clause with the set attributes on the model.

There are plans underway to change this. Discussion [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/876).

Instead of writing your code as above, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
// select * from `books` where `ISBN-13` = '9780440180296'
Book.where({'ISBN-13': '9780440180296'})
  .fetch()
  .then(function(model) {
  // outputs 'Slaughterhouse Five'
  console.log(model.get('title'));
});
```

(I realize you've just copied this straight from the docs.)

If you wish to update a model in place, prefer to use the new [Model#refresh](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-refresh):

```
Book.forge({id: 5}).refresh().then(function (book) {//...
```